# How do I get a JavaScript menu to display vertically?

Tags: javascript, menu

I can not get the menu to display vertically. It only displays horizontally. What am I missing?

```
document.write("<div style='color:blue; font-size:12pt;'>");
document.write('<a href="...">Link 1<\/a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 2<\/a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 3<\/a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 4<\/a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 5<\/a> ');
```

Comment: You could add a `<br>` after each link

Comment: Newlines, probably. `<br>` if you haven’t got any sort of preformatting.

Comment: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Comment: Why are you escaping `/`? makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
document.write("<div style='color:blue; font-size:12pt;'>");
document.write('<a href="...">Link 1</a> <br />');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 2</a> <br />');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 3</a> <br />');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 4</a> <br />');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 5</a> <br />');
```

edit: why are your `</a>` like `<\/a>`??

Comment: Thanks, Sam! That worked! I used the backslash in the link end tag because traditionally it was used to prevent JS from thinking the forward slash ended the string.

Answer (score 0):

A BR tag after each A like others recommended works. You could also use inline CSS and add the style attribute to each A tag (" style='display: block;'").

Personally I'd use an external stylesheet for styles to keep the JS clean, if you had an external stylesheet named style.css. It could have contents:

```
#nav { color:blue; font-size:12pt; }
#nav a { display: block; }
```

Then you could have your JS be like this:

```
document.write('<link href="http://cag.uconn.edu/common/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">');
document.write('<div id="nav">');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 1</a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 2</a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 3</a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 4</a> ');
document.write('<a href="...">Link 5</a> ');
document.write('</div>');
```

Comment: Hi NiHa, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I had an external CSS file already so I added the style attributes. I agree, I like cleaner code the better even if this we site is mindlessly simple.